# JavaScript extend objects and prototypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am creating a framework to simplify the oriented object coding with prototypes. But I am pondering with inheritance in JavaScript.

By default, to extend an object, we write :

```
var B = function() { /*...*/ } ;
B.prototype = new A() ;
```

But what about **A** constructor function requires a parameter ?

```
var A = function(args) {
    if (!args) throw "Arguments required." ;
} ;
```

Or maybe **A** constructor function could also perform unwanted things before **B** was instancied.

What would you suggest to replace the default inheritance behaviour ?
*(I thought about storing all the members of all "classes" to copy while inheriting or mixins.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to inherit from a prototype without calling the constructor, you can use `Object.create()` to do something like this:

```
var B = function() { /*...*/ };

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

In the above, `Object.create(A.prototype)` will return a new object whose prototype is given by `A.prototype`, and it does this without calling `A()`. The second line is there so you can look up the constructor property on any instances of B, and it'll point back to `B()`.

One thing to note is that `Object.create()` is relatively new, so you might need a polyfill for older browsers. You can find one here, along with more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a `defclass` utility function to define "classes" in JavaScript:

```
function defclass(base, body) {
    var uber = base.prototype;
    var prototype = Object.create(uber);
    var constructor = (body.call(prototype, uber), prototype.constructor);
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

Then I use it as follows:

```
var A = defclass(Object, function () {
    this.constructor: function (arg1, arg2) {
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
    }

    this.log = function (which) {
        console.log(which ? this.arg1 : this.arg2);
    };
});
```

Inheritance is dead simple:

```
var B = defclass(A, function (uber) {
    this.constructor = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        uber.constructor.call(this, arg1, arg2);
        this.arg3 = arg3;
    };

    this.log = function (which) {
        uber.log.call(this, which);
        console.log(this.arg3);
    };
});
```

As you can see when we are extending a "class" we use `Object.create`. This is the new way of inheritance. Using `new` is antiquated. In the constructor of `B` we pass arguments to the constructor of `A` using `uber.constructor.call`.

If you like this pattern then you should take a look at the [augment](https://github.com/javascript/augment) library.

Comment: Interesting library indeed. But I'm not a fond of defining attributes and methods with `this.prop = value ;` everywhere.